# How do I run Google Sheets App Script on all sheets (tabs) in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make the following script run on all the sheets(tabs) EXCEPT for one in my Google Sheet.  I need some help.  Thanks.

function myFunction() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var cell = sheet.getRange("B4");

var refresh = parseInt(cell.getValue().toString());
var increment = refresh + 1;

cell.setValue(increment);
}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your script gives you what you expect

All sheets :

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  ss.getSheets().forEach(function (sheet){
    var cell = sheet.getRange("B4");
    var refresh = parseInt(cell.getValue().toString()); 
    var increment = refresh + 1;
    cell.setValue(increment);
  })
}
```

All sheets except a list (Edit by Cooper)

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const exclA = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'];//excluded sheets
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => {!~exclA.indexOf(sh.getName())}).forEach(function (sheet){
    var cell = sheet.getRange("B4");
    var refresh = parseInt(cell.getValue().toString()); 
    var increment = refresh + 1;
    cell.setValue(increment);
  })
}
```

[bitwise not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

Comment: Thank you!   Is there a way to exclude one single sheet(tab) while running it on all the others?

Comment: Thx to Cooper for the complement!